# Table row color - why does this happen?

Tags: javascript, css

I was using changing a row color by setting each cell to the desired color.
Then I found a method where I could change the entire row to a css class and that works fine. However, if I uncomment the old code, the new code below it does not work. Why?

```js
// for (var j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) { 
//  row.cells[j].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
//  row.cells[j].style.color = "lightgreen";
// }        

// set row color using css tr.select td
var table = document.getElementById('table_event_mast');
var RI = row.rowIndex;
table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[RI].className = 'select';
```

Comment: The answer is because `row` is undefined without the upper code. You can see this in the console.

Comment: i believe that a js.style declaration overrides a css declaration. The new code relies on a class and css (the better way), the old code is js.style so it overrides the new code.

Comment: @tstrand66 has it -- setting `.style.whatever` makes an inline CSS rule, which takes precedence over the class-based rules.

Comment: I was not aware that there was a precedence. The code had one function setting all rows and another setting the selected row. I revised the all rows function and not the selected rows function and this explains why it broke. I like the new css method better. Thanks.